# Instafeed.js error after Instagram API Update

Tags: javascript, instagram-api

Struggling with Instafeed.js after updating following Instagram's API update requirements.

I believe I've got all of the user info and credentials working properly, but can't get past an error which seems to be unrelated to the change.

Original functioning application prior to Instagram API update:

http://integrantsightsandsounds.com

Updated page with current Instagram credentials generates the error, 'ReferenceError: Can't find Variable: instafeed'

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(function () { //on DOM ready 
              var userFeed = new instafeed({
                target: 'instagram_list',
          get: 'user',
          userId: 1527608886,
                clientID: 'cb4f0f8196b04aaeaa66e2b253d18b0e',
          limit: 25,
          resolution: 'thumbnail'
                            });
                           userFeed.run();
                            $("#instagram_list").simplyScroll({
              startOnLoad: true,
              speed: 1,
              frameRate: 20,
              orientation: 'horizontal',
              direction: 'forwards',
            }); 
                        });
                    })(jQuery);
```

Far as I can tell, (as someone who knows not a thing about what I'm doing) the Variable hasn't changed from the original, functioning markup, and shouldn't be affected by the updated user credentials.

Tester page:

[http://integrantsightsandsounds.com/instafeedtest/](http://integrantsightsandsounds.com/instafeedtest)

@ladygargar

Comment: Tester page takes to 404 page.

Comment: Link is fixed, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo. The object should be Instafeed and not instafeed (the I is capital).

Answer (score 0):

The instafeed.js is probably missing in your page code.

Try adding:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```

Before your script with the credentials and such.

Note: also, like @10100111001 answered, you have to write `new Instafeed` with the capital I.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I do have the links for the scripts in the header. In fact I even updated with newer versions in the process of trying to make this work, and noticed that in the current documentation at instafeedjs.com, that the Variable new Instafeed has a capital I, as opposed to the original which worked previously with a lower-case i.

Tried it both ways in case the Variable referenced Instafeed with a capital I in the script, but still the same error.

Comment: You are including it wrongly, look at your `http://integrantsightsandsounds.com/instafeed/instafeed.js` file. Its HTML. It should be JS. Check out your browser console, there are an error telling you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` because it expects JavaScript, not HTML. Try with my answer's link.